# simple boot project not working with cljs and async

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async, boot-clj

I have a very simple project. I created the simplest ever project with boot and cljs. It compiled successfully and I was able to see the correct log in the html. When I added a basic support for async I got the message:

```
No such namespace: clojure.core.async, could not locate clojure/core/async.cljs, clojure/core/async.cljc, or Closure namespace "clojure.core.async"
```

The project has just the following structure:

```
exemplo_cljs
    html
       index.html
    src
       exemplo_cljs
           core.cljs
    build.boot
```

The contents of index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

core.cljs

```
(ns exemplo-cljs.core
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as async]))

(def exercise (async/chan))

;; enable cljs to print to the JS console of the browser
(enable-console-print!)

;; print to the console
(println "Hello, World 4!")
```

and build.boot

```
(set-env!
 :source-paths #{"src"}
 :resource-paths #{"html"}

 :dependencies '[[adzerk/boot-cljs "1.7.170-3"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.2.371"]])

(require '[adzerk.boot-cljs :refer [cljs]])
```

The original working project had the same basic structure except for the require and def of a channel in the core.cljs file and the dependency added in the build.boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in ClojureScript, core.async lives under `cljs.core.async` rather than `clojure.core.async`.

So you just need to change your ns form to:

```
(ns exemplo-cljs.core
  (:require [cljs.core.async :as async]))
```

Comment: For some weird reason it worked in lein. I got confused when I migrate to boot.

Comment: Were the cljs versions different?  I thought the cljs/Clojure import namespace thing was changed recently. See: http://blog.fikesfarm.com/posts/2016-07-03-clojurescript-clojure-namespace-aliasing.html